# Replace given substring between two given substrings with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that would look something like this:

```js
var str = '§kfoo bar 123§rfoo bar 123§kfoo bar 123§r';
//                ^                         ^
```

and I want to replace "bar" only when it appears between §k and §r (in this example, the 1st and 3rd ones).

Just replacing them in that string is not an option, that is just an example. The string is a user input, which means the amount of substrings will vary.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: USE:  str = str.replaceAll(/(§k.+?)(bar)(.+?§r)/g, "$1XXX$3")  and replace the XXX with whatever string you want to replace "bar"

Comment: This works, but only for the first time it appears. Is there any way to make it work multiple times?

Comment: Without a while loop with a huge statement, I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```js
let input = "§kfoo bar 123 bar baz§rfoo bar 123 bar§kfoo bar 123 barbar baz§r";

let result = replace(input, "§k", "§r", "bar", "BAR");
console.log(input);
console.log(result);

function replace(input, beginStr, endStr, match, replaceWith) {
    let beginIndex = input.indexOf(beginStr);
    let endIndex = input.indexOf(endStr, beginIndex);

    while (beginIndex > -1 && endIndex > -1) {
        let matchIndex = input.indexOf(match, beginIndex);

        while (matchIndex > beginIndex && matchIndex < endIndex) {
            input = input.substring(0, matchIndex) + replaceWith + input.substring(matchIndex + match.length);

            matchIndex = input.indexOf(match, beginIndex);
        }


        beginIndex = input.indexOf(beginStr, endIndex);
        endIndex = input.indexOf(endStr, beginIndex);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Should output:

```js
§kfoo bar 123 bar baz§rfoo bar 123 bar§kfoo bar 123 barbar baz§r
§kfoo BAR 123 BAR baz§rfoo bar 123 bar§kfoo BAR 123 BARBAR baz§r
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to utilize the `.replace` function and make use of RegEx. In your case this would look like this:

```
str.replaceAll(/(§k.*?)bar(.*?§r)/g, "$1newBar$2");
```

I believe this pattern should work, but I'm not 100% percent sure so let me know if it does and research RegEx pattern matching to further troubleshoot it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.replaceAll called with a non-global RegExp argument

Comment: Right sorry forgot the global flag updating now

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working. The output is "§kfoo bar 123§rfoo bar 123§kfoo bar 123{replacement}§r"

Comment: Okay so it seems that you cant embed other strings into regex, i updated the answer but it seems its matching the most outer §k... §r if theres any pattern inbetween them you're gonna have to find it and im gonna try to find a fix inbetween.

Comment: I added a not operator however the pattern I'm matching is merely an example so i suggest you try and match the actual string, it might prove easier and regex is fairly easy to learn. I guess it might work now tho

Comment: It does not seem to work

Comment: You need to use [Lazy Mode](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode) on the end capture groups.

Comment: Yeah but does then it matches the shortest one, does that really fit with the replaceAll method? Revised the code accordingly hope it works now